# Any benefit in using a form vs a link for logout functionality?

Tags: php, css

I'm building a web app and just working on the logout functionality (simple session unset / meta refresh/redirect code on logout.php)

Possible a simple question (though I've hunted around on Google to no avail), but for the logout button on the site, is there any benefit in using a form that submits to logout.php vs a button graphic with an a href that links to the same page?

Functionally, they both seem to work the same, but is there any potential security issue etc?

Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things that miiiight be relevant here:

1. If it's a form and it POSTs instead of GETting, you will *need* to redirect to get around the usual browser back button + POST data unpleasantness. Of course you already mention redirecting, so this is probably not relevant.
2. Since HTTP GET requests are supposed to be idempotent, "the right way" to do it should be with POST, which means a form. However, this kind of argument lacks practical justification. You should be just fine with links unless some ill-behaved and/or misconfigured browser addon decides to make life difficult for your users.

In essence, there should be no practical difference.

Comment: Practical justification: Pre-caches. When Google release one, a number of forums found that every post an admin viewed got deleted because they used a link instead of a form.

Answer (score 3):

No, unless you need to actually post something to the login script, both methods will work fine.

A link might be easier to crawl by a search engine spider than a form but seeing as this is a logout button, that will not make a difference.

A link has the minor upside that you can easily bookmark it. I would go with a link.

**Edit:** Also check out @dqhendrick's comment about linking. It is probably not overly important for your context, but it's good to keep in mind.

Comment: Thanks Pekka, really appreciate it

Comment: additional note - if you use a GET variable for your logout functionality, someone could send a person that is logged into your website a message with an img tag <img src="index.php?logout=1" />, which would log that person out haha. not really a security risk, but amusing.

Comment: @dqhendricks very good point. Worth noting for a large community web site with user generated content

Comment: @dqhendricks, @Pekka: "privileged" operations (logging out in this case) should be protected against CSRF. Such protection would cause this class of attack to fail. Link: http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries

Comment: @Jon we understand how this works... that's why we mentioned it.

Comment: no one should ever use the $_REQUEST or $_GET array for anything "priviledged".

Comment: @dqhendricks: I don't quite agree with that. Hiding behind POST will not help you avoid getting hacked. And if appropriate measures are taken, then it makes no difference if it's $_POST or $_GET.

Comment: @Jon Some javascript could submit a post, but if they take longer than 5 minutes to fill out a form, they have to start over? Seems like there should be a better way.

Comment: @dqhendricks: Come on... the token valid duration can be whatever you want it to be. Don't pull some detail out of an article I randomly picked from Google to illustrate a basic point and use it as if it were a logical argument.

Comment: @Jon well, there is a valid point in that POST is only vulnerable to JavaScript-powered XSRF, while GET parameters work with a plain URL injected into the victim's system (like in an image URL)... That might make a difference depending on the nature of the system used.

Comment: seems the same method I use to validate that the form submit was not a page refresh, also protects against XSRF. page instance id in forms and session.

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful to consider in addition to the other answers accessibility implications when making this decision. A button signals to a visual user or screenreader an abstract action is going to occur, something more than just navigation.

You wouldn't expect to open sign-out "in a new tab" like a link, for example. A button helps imply extra meaning.